# Java hashes in PHP

Tags: java, php, hash, md5, sha512

I have a Java method that hashes a string with a salt.

I would like to convert to PHP, but I can't figure out how Java's API does this. How would this function look like in PHP?

MD5:

```
public String doHash(String s, String salt) {
    try {
        final MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md5.reset();
        if (salt != null && !salt.isEmpty()) {
            md5.update(salt.getBytes());
        }
        byte[] array = md5.digest(s.getBytes());
        StringBuilder hexData = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            hexData.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1, 3));
        }
        return hexData.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

SHA512:

```
public String doHash(String s, String salt) {
    try {
        final MessageDigest sha512 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        sha512.reset();
        if (salt != null && !salt.isEmpty()) {
            sha512.update(salt.getBytes());
        }
        byte[] data = sha512.digest(s.getBytes());
        StringBuilder hexData = new StringBuilder();
        for (int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < data.length; byteIndex++) {
            hexData.append(Integer.toString((data[byteIndex] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        return hexData.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: so do you want us to write the PHP equivalent for you?

Comment: I would like to understand how it's done, so I can write it myself. But if someone could write the PHP equivalent with explanations, I would be happy as well.